# Payload enrichment via gateway

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to be able to enrich my payload from database stored procedure's ResultSet. Currently I have a service written, which together with a service activator, gets the value from DB and assigns it to some fields.

Now I'd like to switch to `int-jdbc` and have trouble combining `int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway` with `int:enricher`. I wanted to draft a solution based on this [Spring's wiki header enrichment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Enriching-Headers-Using-Gateways) but since `service-interface` parameter of the gateway is required, this approach wouldn't work.

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="input" output-channel="output">                                 
    <int:header name="status" expression="@statusFlow.exchange(#root).payload['STATUS']" />
</int:header-enricher>

<int:gateway id="statusFlow" default-request-channel="getStatusForDeal" />                          

<int:chain input-channel="getStatusForDeal">
    <int:transformer expression="payload.dealId" />
    <jdbc:outbound-gateway query="select status from trade_details where dealId = :payload"
        data-source="dataSource" />                                                        
</int:chain>
```

Do you know how to achieve such payload enrichment in Spring 3.0+ ? In other words: how to achieve payload exchange or which concept replaced it?

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in the wiki article; that technique is now obsolete; you can now set header as well as payload properties with an `<enricher/>` [as documented here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html#payload-enricher).

Comment: Gary, I asked about enricher and just posted an example from the website which related to header-enricher. What I'm asking is how to enrich message using the ResultSet from the `stored-proc-outbound-gateway`

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `but since service-interface parameter of the gateway is required, this approach wouldn't work.`. Please clarify. Read the enricher section and come back with some explicit question(s).